200 amp disconnect and load center wiring and grounding
My mancave/shop consist of a metal building 25'x40' in a small city with no code inspectors, with its own main power/meter and 200amp disconnect  located outside.  I installed a 200 amp circuit breaker load center (HOM3060M200PCVP) inside, both bus neutral/ground bars are connected and have only wired 4 circuits, 240v 4 wire on top left and 240v 3 wire on mid-left plus two 120v circuits for refrigerator and lights. The inside panel secured to wood boards and some of the panel does touch the purlin of the metal building.  The metal building poles are 6" (buried about 3 ft) and 2-3/8 pipe with welded 4" and 10" roof purlins. I do plan to add a 100amp or less sub-panel on the far end of the shop.
Question 1: is the outside panel wired correctly?  not sure why there is additional connections to the right of the neutral.  Box is bonded to the meter and down to the grounding rod.
Question 2:  does the box bonding screw need to be installed?  the tag says, "when it is requires to bond the box to neutral,  use screw on this card.  Insert through hole in neutral bar and thread into hole in the box.  torque to 35 in-lbs after over-coming starting torque.
Question 3: should the inside panel be grounded too, if so, how?
A:  connect a grounding wire to neutral/ground bar and then to a grounding rod outside?
B:  or can i connected it to a 6" pipe that is 7" away?
C:  other?
Question 4: Is it normal to get 120 voltage reading from the hot legs of the 220 outlets (N6-50R and N14-50R) to the metal building pipe/purlin?  The same applies from the hot side of the breakers to the panel and/or building metal.
Thank you for your advice.



Metal pipe/conduit is used as a ground path reducing the need for a separate ground wire.  Ground and neutral is to be bonded together at only one place.  Your disconnect does not look to be bonded, so the bond happens at the next panel(called the main panel).  Even without code/inspectors, code is written mainly to reduce deaths, so going by code is to your best interests/health.

Tks.  Want to be safe.

Can’t quite see the markings but that feeder wire does not look big enough for 200A, even if it’s copper.

all 3 wires from outside emergency disconnect panel to inside main panel replaced with 2 ft of copper 1/0 today.  No 2/0 or green or bare wire available in this small town.  Green grounding screw installed in main panel.

My general sense of this is:
Outside = Emergency Disconnect
With the outside as only an emergency disconnect:

No neutral/ground bond in the disconnect box
Ground should not terminate in this box (currently it does)
No breakers in this box except for one breaker that shuts off the entire service - and this box doesn't even have a place for other breakers, so that's good

Inside = Main Panel
With the inside as the main panel and not a subpanel:

Neutral/ground bonded - i.e., put in a screw where you marked in red
Neutrals and grounds can be mixed on the neutral bars - not ideal, but definitely allowed. If this were a subpanel then grounds would have to be on a separate ground bar
Ground wire (typically 4 AWG, but 6 AWG may be sufficient, bare or green) to ground rods - this is not currently present

Before we get to the ground wire/rod situation:
At a minimum, the metal box of the panel should be connected to ground and in turn (via a single connection in this box) to neutral. While you don't have the official neutral/ground bond in place, you effectively have that done by (a) mixing ground and neutral wires on the neutral bar (so the neutral bar connects to the ground wires that way) and the metal conduit bonds to the metal case (by definition) and bare ground wires effectively bridge everything together. So the end result is that neutral wires, ground wires, metal panel are all the same electrically. That doesn't mean you should (in fact, don't) use ground as neutral or neutral as ground or metal parts as neutral, etc. - But it does mean that, within certain constraints, all of the above would function. But not necessarily in a safe way.
In addition, as long as some of that metal touches bare metal parts of the building, the metal building structure also ends up being the same, which is perfectly fine. Which means in the end that hot-to-neutral, hot-to-ground and hot-to-bare-metal all show the same nominal 120V. Perfectly normal and safe.
The four parts that are problems are:

Neutral/ground bond in main panel - almost a formality but it is a code reuirement and it is trivial to fix - just one little screw.
Wire colors - The neutral wire (both from meter to disconnect and from disconnect to main panel and in the main panel) must be marked with white tape near each termination point. The ground wire (more below) must be marked with green tape near each termination point.
Ground wire is connected in the disconnect box. It is OK for it to be connected there (everything metal all grounded together anyway as described above) but it should not terminate there. Rather, the ground wire to the ground rods should be one continuous wire (no splices) from the main panel all the way to the ground rods.
Ground wire is missing in the main panel. There should be a ground wire going from the main panel, at least 6 AWG but often 4 AWG, all the way from the main panel to the ground rods.

If this were simply grounding an individual circuit then it would be easy - just run a ground wire through the conduit from the main panel to the disconnect box. But there are special rules - basically a single wire end-to-end - for the main ground wire for the building to the ground rods. If these panels are back-to-back then you might be able to:

Disconnect the ground wire and fish it through to the main panel and attach it there.
Run a separate ground wire between the boxes just to ground the disconnect box.

But if that is not the case (or if panels are back-to-back but wire is not quite long enough, which is very likely) then you will need to redo the ground wire and ground rods. Should be able to reuse the ground rods if they are new, but a new wire is needed unless you can rearrange things to get the necessary extra length.
Wire Size
A comment noted concerns about wire size. It looks like the feed wires are 2 AWG. If that's copper then it is good for 115A and, because it is for a full service you get a favorable 83% derate which gets you to 138A but you need 200A. You may be able to replace the disconnect breaker with 125A but the normal thing to do is to replace the wire with 2/0 copper or 4/0 aluminum. This applies to hots and neutral from meter to disconnect and from disconnect to main panel.

Wow.  Going to print, read and digest this info.  Tks

all 3 wires from outside emergency disconnect panel to inside main panel replaced with 2 ft of copper 1/0 today.  No 2/0 or green or bare wire available in this small town.  Green grounding screw installed in main panel.  still working on deciphering the ground issue, will post additional pics with labels for easier reference.

What about from meter to disconnect? That might require the utility to do it, but it looks like the same issue.

Also note that at these sizes you don't need green or bare - black can marked where needed as neutral (white) or ground (green, except actual ground usually does not need to be any larger than 4 AWG).

It isn't perfect but 1/0 good for 180A when feeder, so that's close.
